# strapi Image does not display with next Image

Tags: next.js, strapi

hi i'm using strapi as a backend, trying to display my image in my next application.

i get the url from my apicall but when i put it inside my SRC in my Image component it render a broken image

here is the response named user like this :

```
  {
    Description: 'je crée votre site web',
    Name: '@MattFreelanceWeb',
    createdAt: '2023-05-25T08:54:43.488Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-05-25T13:08:11.726Z',
    publishedAt: '2023-05-25T09:22:19.524Z',
    BgImage: {
      data: {
        id: 1,
        attributes: {
          name: 'bgHero.png',
          alternativeText: null,
          caption: null,
          width: 1664,
          height: 960,
          formats: {
            thumbnail: {
              name: 'thumbnail_bgHero.png',
              hash: 'thumbnail_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36',
              ext: '.png',
              mime: 'image/png',
              path: null,
              width: 245,
              height: 141,
              size: 71.86,
              url: '/uploads/thumbnail_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png'
            },
            small: {
              name: 'small_bgHero.png',
              hash: 'small_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36',
              ext: '.png',
              mime: 'image/png',
              path: null,
              width: 500,
              height: 288,
              size: 275.46,
              url: '/uploads/small_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png'
            },
            medium: {
              name: 'medium_bgHero.png',
              hash: 'medium_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36',
              ext: '.png',
              mime: 'image/png',
              path: null,
              width: 750,
              height: 433,
              size: 609.12,
              url: '/uploads/medium_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png'
            },
            large: {
              name: 'large_bgHero.png',
              hash: 'large_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36',
              ext: '.png',
              mime: 'image/png',
              path: null,
              width: 1000,
              height: 577,
              size: 1081.51,
              url: '/uploads/large_bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png'
            }
          },
          hash: 'bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36',
          ext: '.png',
          mime: 'image/png',
          size: 843.61,
          url: '/uploads/bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png',
          previewUrl: null,
          provider: 'local',
          provider_metadata: null,
          createdAt: '2023-05-25T13:07:45.022Z',
          updatedAt: '2023-05-25T13:07:45.022Z'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

in my component i set a variable call ImageSrc like this:

```
  let imageSrc = `${"http://localhost:1337"}${
    user?.BgImage.data.attributes.url
  }`;
```

same thing for the width, height and alt that i put inside my Image component :

```
 <Image src={imageSrc} alt={imageAlt} width={imageWidth} height={imageHeight}  className="h-screen object-cover"/>
```

and i render a broken image :s and this even when i put the direct url http://localhost:1337/uploads/bg_Hero_8e1e23dc36.png in my src

i don't understand, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue using a loader prop in the Image component explanation here : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `unoptimized` on the next/image component fixed the issue for me. Essentially, if you are running Strapi and Next.js on the same server, image optimization may have difficulty optimizing the image, resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
edit: `next.config.mjs`

```
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: '1337',
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

Don't forget, restart next server, if is running.

You can create helper:

```js
export const getStrapiMedia = (url) => {
  return `http://localhost:1337${url}`;
};
```

After can you use it...

```
<Image src={getStrapiMedia(motiveData.url)} />
```